# Adjusting post width according to the image size

Tags: css, images

I am building a theme for a comic site. It seems some images are bigger than the post size. I need to resize the images according to the **Original Image size**. Can I achieve this through CSS? It doesn't matter if it extends the screen-size and scrolling window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/950x450/" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post { 
    width: 500px;
}

.post img.thumb {
    width: 100%; /* fill available space of parent and keep aspect ratio */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/